# Get filename from string-path?

Tags: string, batch-file, filenames

How do I get the filename from this string?

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\hello\test.txt"
```

output:

```
"test.txt"
```

I really tried to find this one before posting, but all the results were contaminated, they talk about getting filenames from current dir (I must work with strings only)

Comment: `cd` to that directory and type `dir /b`

Comment: @Marc that string is created with a loop, I think accessing 200-300 dirs isn't wise. I really must work strings only, but thanks for the alternative

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
for %%F in ("C:\Documents and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\hello\test.txt") do echo %%~nxF
```

Type `HELP FOR` for more info.

**Method 2**

```
call :sub "C:\Documents and Settings\Usuario\Escritorio\hello\test.txt"
exit /b

:sub
echo %~nx1
exit /b
```

Type `HELP CALL` for more info.

Comment: please, can you explain "%~nx1"?

Comment: @Yukulélé - It modifies the expansion of `%1`, treating it as a file path and expanding to the name and extension, disregarding drive and path. Type `HELP CALL` or `CALL /?` from the command prompt for more information about all of the parameter expansion modifiers.

Comment: thanks, I found more details here http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 28):

if your path comes as a parameter, just use:

`%~nx1` (1 is for the first param and we suppose it's the first one)

`echo %~nx1` would return directly test.txt

Comment: I just needed this badly myself and, for that particular case (as parameter), it's much more shorter and elegant.

Comment: of course `%~nx2` or `%~nx3` if passed as second/third parameter...

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you need the the names of files under the "c:\temp" directory tree (including sub-directories):

```
FOR /R c:\temp %i in (*.*) do echo %~nxi
```