# Convert list of paths to list of filenames

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, filenames

**Background**

I find myself often copying file paths to the clipboard, which is somewhat cumbersome to do from Windows Explorer.

So I wrote a little `.bat` file to put into the `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\` folder utilising the [`CLIP` executable](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/5182-tip-use-clip-exe-manage-clipboard-cmd.html) to copy a list of the selected file paths to the clipboard. This file consists only of a single line:

```
echo|set /p= "%*" | clip.exe
```

Which works quite nicely, I can select one or more filenames in Explorer, right-click on them and "Send To" the `.bat` file, which copies them to the clipboard. Each file path is complete and separated from the others by a space character.

**Question**

Sometimes, I don't want to copy a list of the full file paths, but would prefer to have a list of just the filenames with their extensions. I know how to do that conversion for single file paths, using the `%~nx` syntax as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10393352/897968) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259829/897968).

I tried different combinations of these but can't seem to find a workable solution for my **list** of paths. The following code `echo`s the filenames correctly:

```
for %%F in (%*) do echo %%~nxF
```

...but how do I combine them to pass through to `CLIP`? Do I have to do string concatenation? Maybe in a subroutine to be `call`ed, or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will put each file name on a separate line within the clipboard:

```
@(for %%F in (%*) do @echo %%~nxF)|clip
```

If you prefer, the following will put a space delimited list of file names on a single line, with quotes around each file name.

```
@(for %%F in (%*) do @<nul set /p =""%%~nxF" ")|clip
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just:

```
echo|set /p= "%~nx*" | clip.exe
```

Comment: Did you try it? `The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~nx*"`

Comment: On my Windows 7 system, this produces the error message just as @JosefZ said.